# CTCI 6TH EDITION 1.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Question : Check if s2 is a rotation of s1.

```py
def check(s1, s2):

  s1 += s1
  return (s1.find(s2) != -1)

s1 = 'abcd'
s2 = 'dabc'
print(check(s1, s2))

METHOD 2

def check(s1, s2):

  s1 = list(s1)
  s2 = list(s2)

  for _ in range (len(s2)):
    if s1 != s2:
      curr = s2.pop()
      s2.insert(0,curr)
    else:
      return True
  return False

s1 = 'abcd'
s2 = 'dabc'
print(check(s1, s2))
```

I would like to compare these two WORKING AND COMPLETED solutions, both run in O(N) time, but im not sure about the space complexities.

For the first one there is a string append, so it takes O(N) space proportional to the length of s1 ?
In the second case its O(Len(s1)+len(s2)) space for the two array creations ?

Thank you

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted, I think space complexity can be approximated to O(N) in both cases (where N is `len(s2)`). Big O notation is fuzzy by design.

Comment: Both are O(n), because `n` is the combined length of `s1` and `s2`. Further, the return value of `False` when `s1` and `s2` have different lengths can be found without any additional space.

Comment: The second one does *not* run in O(n) time, because `s2.insert(0, curr)` itself is an O(n) operation, and it is performed O(n) times. You can mitigate that however, by using a `collections.deque` instead of a list.

Comment: I guess you can make the second solution O(n) using string slices - since Python strings are immutable the space complexity is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

```
In [15]: s1 = 'abcd' 
    ...: s2 = 'dabc'                                                                                                                                                                          

In [16]: set(s1).difference(set(s2))                                                                                                                                                          
Out[16]: set()


In [23]: s1 = 'abcder' 
    ...: s2 = 'dabc'                                                                                                                                                                          

In [24]: set(s1).difference(set(s2))                                                                                                                                                          
Out[24]: {'e', 'r'}
```

You can solve it with sets: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

example:

```
def check(s1, s2): 
    return not set(s1).symmetric_difference(set(s2)) and len(s1) == len(s2)
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct: "dcba"  is not a rotation of "abcd".

Comment: @PauloScardine I think OP want to compare two strings to find difference. But I also think you are rigth thx. I'll fix my example

Comment: rotated strings are a small subset of strings containing the same characters - they always have the same length and characters are in the same order relative to each other.

Comment: @PauloScardine Yep, It didn't work for rotated strings but for other examples I guess it will work faster

Comment: BTW your function body can be abbreviated to just `return not set(s1).symmetric_difference(set(s2)) and len(s1) == len(s2)`

Comment: The problem statement is "Check if s2 is a **rotation** of s1.", I'm under the impression you understood it as "Check if s2 contains the same character set as s1".

Comment: @PauloScardine thank you for pythonic way: `return not set(s1).symmetric_difference(set(s2)) and len(s1) == len(s2)`